# Asignar un contador como Id a una etiqueta HTML

Tags: c#, html, html5, asp.net, razor

Mi duda es la siguiente, en mi proyecto de `ASP.NET`, tengo en una vista, el `foreach` de razor con el que imprimo mis valores del modelo, y se crea un div por cada iteración, lo que necesito es que este `div` tenga un id `autoincrementable`, debido a la logica de algunas funciones de JS que tengo.

¿Como puedo lograr esto?

Ya que si asigno una variable automáticamente me transforma el carácter en un `string` y no toma el valor numérico.

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcFrontBolsaTrabajo.Models.ParaProcReportes.PostulacionesXCandidatoModel>
@using Newtonsoft.Json;

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutCandidato.cshtml";
}


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PostulacionesXCandidato";
}
    <div id="divP">

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
                    <div class="panel panel-primary " id=""  style="display:inline-block; text-align:center; width: 16%; margin: 5%;">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TituloVacante)
                    </div>
                    <p>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombresoc)
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombreciu)
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FechaPostulacionvc)
                    </p>
                    <div>

                    </div>
                </div>

        }
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaras la variable en tu vista *Razor* antes del `foreach`

```
@{int contador= 1; }
```

Y en su `foreach` , imprimiría el valor de la variable en el `id` del `div` y al final incrementaría.

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
  {
   <div class="panel panel-primary " id="@contador" 
    style="display:inline-block; text-align:center; width: 16%; margin: 5%;">
     /* Demás columnas*/
     //Incrementamos el Valor
      contador = contador + 1;
 }
```

> [Referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7534952/6502043)

Comment: Muchas gracias!, por fin pude concluir el modulo en el que estaba trabajando, funciono a la perfección.

Answer (score 0):

en la vista declaras en el entorno:

```
@{
    int contador= 1;

}
```

y antes de finalizar el ciclo no olvides aumentar el contador:

```
contador++;
```